# Problems with cin.getline()

Tags: c++, input, cin

There is this website called URI which has a lot of problems for you solve, I was solving this one problem but apparently something is happening that my program is getting the wrong input and I have no idea why. This is the URI problem:

```
Maria has just started as graduate student in a medical school and she's needing
your help to organize a laboratory experiment which she is responsible about.
She wants to know, at the end of the year, how many animals were used in this
laboratory and the percentage of each type of animal is used at all.

This laboratory uses in particular three types of animals: frogs, rats and
rabbits. To obtain this information, it knows exactly the number of experiments
that were performed, the type and quantity of each animal is used in each
experiment.

Input

The first line of input contains an integer N indicating the number of test
cases that follows. Each test case contains an integer Amount (1 ≤ Amount ≤ 15)
which represents the amount of animal used and a character Type ('C', 'R' or
'S'), indicating the type of animal:
- C: Coelho (rabbit in portuguese)
- R: Rato (rat  in portuguese)
- S: Sapo (frog in portuguese)

Output

Print the total of animals used, the total of each type of animal and the
percentual of each one in relation of the total of animals used. The percentual
must be printed with 2 digits after the decimal point.

Input example:
10
10 C
6 R
15 S
5 C
14 R
9 C
6 R
8 S
5 C
14 R

Output example:
Total: 92 cobaias
Total de coelhos: 29
Total de ratos: 40
Total de sapos: 23
Percentual de coelhos: 31.52 %
Percentual de ratos: 43.48 %
Percentual de sapos: 25.00 %
```

And this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    /**
     * Escreva a sua solução aqui
     * Code your solution here
     * Escriba su solución aquí
     */
     char input[5],num_char[2];
     int coelho = 0, rato = 0, sapo = 0,op, num, index;
     cin >> op;//Get how many time the loop will happen

     for(int i=0;i<op;i++){
        index = 0;
        fflush(stdin);
         cin.getline(input,4);
         //Copy the number part of  the input to the num_char[]  and  converts it to int
         while(input[index] != ' '){
            num_char[index] = input[index];
            index++;
         }
         num = atoi(num_char);
         //Get what animal is being tested
         if(input[index+1] == 'R') rato +=num;
         else if(input[index+1] == 'C') coelho +=num;
         else if(input[index+1] == 'S') sapo +=num;
     }
    //Print output
     cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
     cout << "Total: " << rato+sapo+coelho << " cobaias" << endl;
     cout << "Total de coelhos: " << coelho << endl;
     cout << "Total de ratos: " << rato << endl;
     cout << "Total de sapos: " << sapo << endl;
     cout << "Percentual de coelhos: " << coelho*100.0/(rato+sapo+coelho) << "%" << endl;
     cout << "Percentual de ratos: " << rato*100.0/(rato+sapo+coelho) << "%" << endl;
     cout << "Percentual de sapos: " << sapo*100.0/(rato+sapo+coelho) << "%" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the webpage of the problem:
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1094

Comment: First of all, don't call `fflush` on `stdin`, it's technically undefined behavior. Secondly, you don't really need `getline` (neither the member-function nor the standalone function), since all data lines contains only a single intger and a single character you can use the normal input operator `>>`.

Comment: isn't cin >> string vulnerable to buffer overflow? I was taught to avoid using the  >> operator as much as possible. And the fflush(stdin) gets rid of many problems you can have with memory trash. At least that's how they've been teaching on my first year in university

Comment: Why would you want to read a string? The input contains *integers* and *characters* (but be careful when reading the character so you don't read the space between the number and the letter). Also, if reading into a `std::string` it will increase its size as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your trouble is that the `atoi` function expects a C-style string, and as you *should* know all C-style strings have a special terminator character, which I don't see you having which leads to *undefined behavior* as `atoi` goes out of bounds trying to look for the terminator character.

The solution? For your current solution you need to add the string terminator. A better solution? Use the input operators `>>` as I said in my comment, and you will have no need to use strings or `atoi`.

Comment: I tried already, still didn't work

Comment: @JoãoAreias can you update your question to show that you attempted his suggestions and maybe we can figure out why it still didn't work

Comment: @JoãoAreias Well that's the most obvious error in the code you *show*, and since you don't give more details it's really hard to say anything else.